# Luxon with Typescript: TS2339: Property 'c' does not exist on type 'DateTime'

Tags: typescript, luxon

I have been trying to translate a JS function to TS, in which I use [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/).

The problem is that when I try to access the `c` property from [now()](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/tour?id=get-the-current-date-and-time), I get the following error `Typescript: TS2339: Property 'c' does not exist on type 'DateTime'.`

```
import { DateTime as Luxon } from 'luxon';

const getCurrentHour = (): number => {
  const dTime = Luxon.now();
  return dTime.c.hour;
}

console.log(typeof Luxon.now()); // I get "DateTime"
console.log(Luxon.now()); // I can see the "c" property
```

I know that JavaScript's DateTime interface does not have this `c` property, but how do I manage to write this code with Luxon and TypeScript? I have installed [@types/luxon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/luxon) and tried to find a type export there, but did not succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem.
try `return dTime.hour` instead of `return dTime.c.hour`

Comment: that did the trick, thank you :)